# Signal broadcasting using TCP

Tags: tcp, broadcasting

Is there any method to broadcast a signal or message in TCP? I know that for broadcasting UDP is used.
For example multiple clients connected with server and server sends a broadcast signal to all of connected clients at the same time. Is it possible using TCP?

Answer (score 1):

No, TCP is connection oriented and designed for single end to end communications.

Comment: Ok then what i will do to handle this because i want to this in tcp? Any suggestion or method?

Comment: @Umarniaz: [Use a different transport layer](http://www.zeromq.org). And, please, read its documentation before making any further questions.

Comment: If you want to "broadcast" to a limited number of clients just send the message to each client on its own tcp connection, preferably using multithreading to minimize delays